# Filing for Education Expenses for Dependent

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, taxes, education

My brother is my dependent and he lives with me! He goes to university and pay international tuition fees. Since, he has to pay international tuition our whole family contributes small amounts to make up for his fees. Now it is tax time and my family members are asking me to claim all his fees. I have only contributed a small amount like $1000. How should I go about claiming tax deductions on the education expenses for my brother which was contributed by the whole family and not only me!

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have to consult a tax attorney to get a definitive answer, but my guess is that you can only claim deductions for your personal contribution.